# ReWrite rules in Apache to trigger PHP

Tags: php, apache, containers, centos7

So, I am required to get a PHP web service working in Apache in a CentOS7 container. To do so, I grabbed a CentOS7 container, added the required rpm via yum install, watched it drag in all of its dependencies, and then I dropped this fragment into /etc/httpd/conf.d.

```
ServerName mbg-webrtc-web

RewriteEngine on
LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined_virtual

CustomLog /dev/stderr combined_virtual
ErrorLog /dev/stderr
TransferLog /dev/stdout

LogLevel info rewrite:trace6

Alias /webrtc /opt/a5000/infra/utd/www/webrtc

RewriteRule ^/webrtc/api/index.php.*$  - [L]
RewriteRule ^/webrtc/api/(.*)$ /webrtc/api/index.php [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^/webrtc /notfound [R,L]

<Directory "/opt/a5000/infra/utd/www/webrtc">
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>
```

Now, the client calls to itself via an FQDN that is proxies through an nginx container on to this url: https://mbg-webrtc-web/webrtc/api/IcpSideInfo

The rewrite rules, which work on a standalone server platform running Apache 2.4 and CentOS7, are supposed to transform that to execute the index.php code, where it will look at its invoked path and run the internal IcpSideInfo function call.

But, the rewrite rules do not appear to be hit. No logging is seen from them and no rewriting happens. I get a 404 because the Alias works and apache tries to resolve to a local file which does not exist. I am stumped.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: You enabled mod_rewrite (`RewriteEngine on`) and your syntax looks good.  You also enabled verbose tracing (`LogLevel info rewrite:trace6`).  Q: What exactly do the logs say?  Also: run `phpinfo();` to confirm mod_rewrite (and PHP itself!) are actually loaded.

Comment: phpinfo runs and says that mod_rewrite is loaded.

Comment: And no mention of mod_rewrite appears in the logs at all, they just show the 404 error on /webrtc/api/IcpSideInfo.